# html5: three-rows flexbox with fixed top/bottom and scrollable middle

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to make an `html5` flexbox layout with fixed `header/footer` and a scrollable `article` section like the following for *firefox* 24 and *chromium* 31?

```
+----------+
| header   |
+----------+
| article ||
|         ||
|         ||
|         ||
+----------+
| footer   |
+----------+
```

I've tried this (simplified):

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  flex: 1;
}
article {
  flex: 8;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
footer {
  flex: 1;
}
```

and now I'm trying to fill the remain space with the `article`, but if the contents height is smaller than the window height, the footer is not fixed and if it's bigger, the footer scrolls out of the viewable area...

Comment: Why does flex equal 8 for article?

Comment: @PaulTotzke I'll swallow the bait here. Nobody knows, probably. People paste things through 8 layers of indirection these days. The snippet may have been originally written for a specific case where it was genuinely applicable, and survived through copy pasting across Internet when it also landed here. There is seldom need to use any other value than `1` for `flex-grow`, it's the `flex-basis` people usually want. Guys, just read https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox/, it's actually not difficult to read and understand, I am not even native English speaker and I managed (over the course of 3 days).

Comment: That's what I thought but sometimes there is some weird browser fix. Just got to be sure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You probably need to make sure the body is 100% high:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnBhH/2/).

Comment: your implementation is correct but has a fault, your title and footer size is relevant to page size. not desirable in most cases. here is alternate solution https://jsfiddle.net/njfmt7w0/

Comment: Seriously can't upvote this^^ comment enough. Exactly the issue I was having.

Comment: The link on mamu's comment is a very simple and clean example.  TY

Comment: On a mobile phone the menubar/addressbar normally disappear when you start scrolling. The benefit of that is that you get the full browser height available. But this layout prevents this behavior, which I think is not desirable. Also in Safari on iPad I noticed that the scrolled element stops moving as soon as you don't move your finger. Normally it takes a while for the scrolling to stop. I would not use this for any layout.

Comment: Mamu's solution is incorrect, because the article doesn't stretch to fill available space, so the footer can move upward. I would take Moob's solution but remove `flex: 1` from the header and footer to make them fixed-size. Also, use `overflow-y: auto` instead of `overflow-y: scroll` to make the scrollbar disappear when it is not needed.