# Div height: 100% between 2 divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically what I have are 3 divs. top , middle , bottom.
Top has a height of 60px;
Bottom has a height of 60px;
I want middle to be the height between Top and Bottom. I tried with `height: 100%;` but it didn't seem to work.

If I set the height of `.middle` it wont do anything. If I decide to put a `height : 10px;` or padding on it It WILL show up for some reason.

HTML code :

```css
html,
body{
    height:100%;
 background-color: #181818;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
}

.nopadding {
 padding: 0 !important;
 margin: 0 !important;
}

.topbanner {
 background-color: #282828;
 display:block;
  height: 76px;
}

.leftbanner {
 background-color: #282828;
 height: 100%;
}

.middlebanner {
 background-color: #181818;
 height: 100%;
 
}

.rightbanner {
 background-color: #282828;
 height: 100%;
}

.bottombanner {
 background-color:#282828;
 height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0;
}

.middle{
 height: 100%;
}

.row {

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="top" id="header">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="topbanner">
    
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle" id="middle">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 nopadding">
     <div class="leftbanner">
  
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-8 nopadding">
     <div class="middlebanner">
     
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-2 nopadding">
     <div class="rightbanner">
     
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="bottom" id="footer">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="bottombanner">
   
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5: three-rows flexbox with fixed top/bottom and scrollable middle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477707/html5-three-rows-flexbox-with-fixed-top-bottom-and-scrollable-middle)

Comment: Please don't update your question with the code from the answers.

Comment: Please don't do that, the question should only show ***the original problem***.

Comment: As my answer was helpful, could you click the checkmark left to my answer, below "0", so as it becomes green.

Answer (score 1):

`calc()` would work there.

```
height:calc(100% - 120px);
```

Or you could fix'ed position that div:

```
div {
   position:fixed;
   right:0; left:0;
   bottom:60px;
   top:60px;
}
```

Comment: added height:calc(100%-120px); to the .middle class. Didnt seem to work

Comment: min-heigth: calc(100vh - 120px);

Comment: Support for calc isnt enough if you want all browsers in sync

Comment: @Martijn Ok. add to body min-height: 100vh;

Comment: added  
min-heigth: calc(100vh - 120px); to .middle class didnt work.

Comment: @Ricy Check the second part of the answer.

Comment: There **must** be a space between `100%` and `-` and `120px`.

Comment: Tried: 

.middle{
   position:absolute;
   right:0; left:0;
   bottom:60px;
   top:60px;
}

.row {
   position:absolute;
   right:0; left:0;
   bottom:60px;
   top:60px;
}

what happened is what you can see in this GYAZO
https://gyazo.com/2d4b36f9e5185d326f13e73cb4ced466

Comment: @RicyGum why do u use absolutely? jast position:fixed for .top and .bottom

Comment: Haha, my mistake! Of course it's `fixed`, what's up with me. @Ricy - see the edit.

Comment: Hey! Was busy with updating the thread with the .div you sent in this answer. still doesnt work but maybe it is better if you can view it like that in the OP

Comment: @Ricy Please don't update the thread with the code from the answers.

Comment: Oh Im sorry for that! this is my first time using stackoverflow. Should have read documentation :/

Comment: Relax guys, silent. This is a noob. ))) Welcome. )))

Comment: Haha ;) Thanks anyways guys! And yes indeed, I am a big n00b

Answer (score 1):

You could use the flex box model (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox/), which is sort of designed to solve the kind of problem you are trying to solve:

```
.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.top, .bottom {
    height: 60px;
}

.middle {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Just keep in mind that `body` and `html` have automatic height initially, so even if your `.container-fluid` specifies `height: 100%`, it will have to fit within the actual height of the document body which is initially "compact", just as `html` element is. Try `html, body { height: 100%; }` for size (pun intended).

The flex box model also gives you possibility to define how your flex items (children of a *flex container* which is the nearest parent with `display: flex`, in this case the `.container-fluid` element) react as their content grows or shrinks.

Finally, the usual disclaimer: support for flex box is much improved but may not be to your liking, assess its viability according to your project constraints.

Answer (score 0):

with the flex model, `flex:1;` is the rule you may want to know:

example with a simple template *( feed each pieces with your contents and your own styles )*

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #181818;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color:white;
}
header,
footer,
aside {
  background: #282828
}
/* layout */

body,
main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  /* should show a scrollbar ? if yes then */
  overflow:auto;
}
body {
  flex-flow: column;
}
header,
footer {
  min-height: 60px;
  /* height: 60px; or
   whatever, but it can just grow from content if you wish without height nor min-height*/
}
section {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
}
aside {
  flex: 1;
}

/* see me **/
* {box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px;}
```

```html
<header>your head stuff here</header>
<main>
  <aside>
    on left
  </aside>
  <section>
    on middle
  </section>
  <aside>
    on right
  </aside>
</main>
<footer>
  footer stuff
</footer>
```